# Fixing GRUB after cloning a drive with RSYNC

Tags: grub, cloning

I have a remote server (no physical access to it) that I need to clone locally.  So, I attached a secondary HD to a local linux server, created the partitions boot, swap and root and rsync'd all the data from the remote server.  The copy went smoothly but when I try to activate grub so the new drive is bootable this is what happens (the remote server has LVM partitions while on the local drive I just created boot, swap and root normally):

I mount the copied image this way:

```
mount /dev/sdb3 /mount && mount /dev/sdb1 /mount/boot/

mount --bind /dev /mount/dev && mount --bind /dev/pts /mount/dev/pts && mount --bind /proc /mount/proc && mount --bind /sys /mount/sys
chroot /mount
```

Then I attempt to install grub:

```
grub-install /dev/sdb
```

Could not find device for `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root`

The file `/boot/grub/stage1` not read correctly.

(and I tried to boot into this drive but I get a "grub rescue" prompt)

`/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root` is the root partition of the remote server.  I don't know what I need to do here. I tried removing the `/boot/grub/` folder attempting a fresh grub install but the same happens.  How can I tell grub that now the root partition is `/dev/sda3` or how would you go about fixing this?

grub.conf file:

```
default=0

timeout=5

splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz

hiddenmenu

title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64)

        root (hd0,0)

        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 root=/dev/sda1

        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64.img
```

fdisk -l output on the cloned drive:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sdb1   *           1          66      524288   83  Linux

Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.

/dev/sdb2              66        2155    16777216   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.

/dev/sdb3            2155       41774   318241792   83  Linux

Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.
```

Comment: You'll certainly need to update fstab, if you haven't already. That might well be where `grub-install` gets its device ideas.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I forgot to mention that but I did update fstab before installing grub, so grub is getting the LVM info elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to update both the `/etc/fstab` file and also the GRUB configs to reflect the change from LVM to not LVM.  If you're using original GRUB (ie the better version of GRUB) you can just make the device changes in `/boot/grub/grub.conf`.  If you're using GRUB2 (ie. the annoying version of GRUB) you'll need to change a bunch of files that are most likely located in `/etc/defaults/grub/`.  It may be worth the time to do a search of the whole `/etc` directory for something like 'VolGroup' just to see where all the LVM devices are referenced because there may be other services referring to the actual device instead of the mount (specifically, udev?).

`grep -r 'VolGroup' /etc`

Comment: Thanks, David.  I updated fstab before trying to install grub so that's not it.  In /etc there's only some files within /dev/lvm with the 'VolGroup' string.  In /boot/ only grub/grub.conf comes up with matches, like this: 

/boot/grub/grub.conf:   kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/sda3 rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb crashkernel=auto quiet KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM pcie_aspm=off

How can I fix that line?  I replaced the old path with /dev/sda3 but I dunno what to do with the rest 'n still won't work.

Comment: Try `kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/sda3 rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb crashkernel=auto quiet KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM pcie_aspm=off`

Comment: There also may be tools to automagically detect your available kernels and rebuild the grub.conf file.  If those exist and what they're called would be distro dependent but given the complexity of that `kernel` line I'm guessing it wasn't written by hand.

Comment: The grub file has #Generated by Anaconda.
Now after boot I just get a grub> prmpt.  If I type "ls" I get:
(hd0)(hd0,msdos3)(hd0,msdos2)(hd0,msdos1)(fd0)
But the grub.conf file has:
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/sda3 rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb crashkernel=auto quiet KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM pcie_aspm=off
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64.img
Should I change where it says "root (hd0,0)" to "root(hd0,msdosX)?

Comment: I did some Googling and didn't find much on anaconda.  I normally write my `grub.conf` files by hand but it's been a while since I've used a separate `/boot` partition so I'm a little rusty on the details.  I thin all you need on the kernel line is `kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 root=/dev/sdb1`

Comment: How did you create the partitions on these new drives?  They should be showing up as `(hd0,0)` not `(hd0,msdos0)`.  You may need to re-partition the drives and redo the filesystem.  If you do, don't waste your time with a separate boot partition.  It'll work fine all as one.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas David!  I modified the kernel line but still get grub> prompt.  I edited my question to include the current grub.conf file.  Regarding the partitions I created them normally with fdisk.  I included the fdisk -l result in my question as well.  Let me know if you can think of anything else.

Comment: Sorry.  I got my sda's and sdb's confused.  Change the `root` on your kernel line to be `/dev/sdb1`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be sdA1?  The cloned disk becomes the primary and only disk in the system when I run the tests.  (I need to have it as secondary to boot from another one to do the edits on the files).

Comment: I didn't realize the other drive was being removed.  Yes. It should be `sda` in that case.  One other thing I had wrong...the `root=` directive points to the device that should be mounted as the root of the filesystem...that should be `/dev/sda3`

Comment: No luck.  Still getting the grub prompt.  Thanks for the ideas anyway, David.  Have a good one.